# Zend database adapter - register in bootstrap.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to register my default database adapter in my bootstrap.php file so that I can access it where ever I am. This is my code so far:

```
//bootstrap.php
protected function _initDb()
{
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory(Zend_Registry::get('configuration')
                                       ->resources->db->adapter, 
                                  Zend_Registry::get('configuration')
                                       ->resources->db->params->toArray());

    Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $dbAdapter);
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter);
}
```

I am then trying to call it in one of my models by saying:

```
//exampleModel.php
$select = $this->_getDbAdapter()
                ->select()
                ->from(array('t' => $this->_getTable()->getName()), 
                       array('name'))....
```

However I am just getting the error:

```
Call to undefined method Application_Model_Example::_getdbAdapter() in...
```

So obviously it is looking for it within my current class and can't find it...

Comment: Have you tried doing this in application.ini? I think that's a better place to do it.

Comment: doing what???? i have declared my db host, name and password etc in application ini but i am noe trying to create the adapter

Comment: it's already created. have you read this? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.db

Comment: please show your Application_Model_Example class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this in your Model_Example

```
public function _getSqlAdapter()
{
    return Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter');
}
```

Or directly call `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()` instead of `$this->_getDbAdapter()`

Comment: thanks man so obvious now i see... is there somewhere i can put this method so that i dont have to have it in every model and i can just say $select = $this->_getDbAdapter()?

Comment: You can create an Abstract Model and extend it inside all your models or just call `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()`

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided you don't appear to be calling it the adapter from the registry. You would need to use `Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter');`

What class does Application_Model_Example extend?

Answer (score 0):

I have `Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter);` in my bootstrap (notice its `Zend_Db_Table`, not `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`).

Then in my models, I would just use

```
$select = $this->->select()
    ->from(array('t' => $this->_getTable()->getName()), array('name'))....
```

assuming your model extends `Zend_Db_Table`?